# Counting number of occurences using a for loop

Tags: r

I currently have two vectors, unique and words. They are both vectors containing only words. Both consist of one column and alot of rows containg only a single word. 'Words' contains duplicates, while 'unique' does not.

Both vectors thus look like this:

```
1 hello
2 monkey
3 start
4 music
...
```

What I want to do is basically loop through the 'unique' vector and count how many times each word occurs in the 'words' vector.

Currently I have this piece of code

```
for (i in unique) {print(sum(words$words == i))}
```

However, when I run this line, it just gives me an error message.

How can I tackle this problem? I just can't seem to solve this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is a built in `table()` function for this. Try `table(words$words)` or `as.data.frame(table(words$words))` depending on how you want the output formatted.

Comment: I think that I didn't state my problem correctly. The 'unique' vector could contain words which are not present in the 'words' vector. That is why I tried looping through the 'unique' vector, and calculate the sum of occurences for each word in the 'words' vector.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: Then you just need to call factor() first with the levels= you  want counts for.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information to enable us to debug the code you've written, but the following should help you:

```
# Create the word list
words <- c('aardvark', 'bonobo', 'aardvark', 'cougar', 'bonobo', 'aardvark', 'dingo', 'cougar', 'bonobo', 'aardvark')

# add one extra word to our unique word list
# Note that 'unique' is already a function in R, so I'm not using it as a name
uniq <- c(unique(words), 'elephant')

# Using a for loop
for (i in uniq) {
    cat('Count of ', i, ': ', sum(words == i), '\n', sep='')
}

> Count of aardvark: 4
> Count of bonobo: 3
> Count of cougar: 2
> Count of dingo: 1
> Count of elephant: 0

# Without a loop
table(factor(words, levels=uniq))
> aardvark   bonobo   cougar    dingo elephant 
>   4        3        2        1        0
```

I'm guessing your code doesn't work because `words$words` won't work if your words list is a vector.